# Problem with making double click macro in Python using Pynput

Tags: python, macros, pynput

This is the code:

```
from pynput import keyboard, mouse
from time import sleep

clicked = False

mouseC = mouse.Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.left and pressed:
        if not clicked:
            execute()

def execute():
    global clicked

    clicked = True
    sleep(0.1)
    mouseC.press(mouse.Button.left)
    mouseC.release(mouse.Button.left)
    clicked = False

with mouse.Listener(on_click = on_click) as lstnr:
    lstnr.join()
```

So, i'am trying to make a macro in Python using Pynput that triggers another click when the left mouse button is clicked, but i'am having a problem with it. When the second click is generated by the script it is detected by the Pynput listener and that creates a infinite loop of click.

I already try to solve this problem by making a condition in the "on_click" listener that only triggers if the a variable "clicked" is set to False. When the listener triggers, it execute a function that set the "clicked" variable to True right before the second click is generated and after that it set the variable to False again, allowing you to make another click. But that doenst seams to work and somehow the clicking loop still happening.

I hope you guys understand my bad english.

Comment: I can’t test anything right now but I think your problem might be that the callbacks are run one after the other and so your variable is both set and unset before the next click is registered, so your system won’t have any effect. If you don’t need it to work for clicking more than 5 times a second, you can probably just have a variable that toggles between True and False. Since a click will always be followed by a programmed click, this might work quite well. Let me know if you want some example code and I’ll try to make something.

Comment: @Cmd858 a example code would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally discovery how to make it work. So i just add a count variable that increase by 1 each time a click is detected and create a condition that the second click will only hapen if the count hites 2. I don't know exaclly how this works but it works so i'm happy with it.

The code:

```
from pynput import mouse
from time import sleep

mouseC = mouse.Controller()
count = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global count
    if button == mouse.Button.left and pressed:
        count = count + 1
        if count == 2:
            count = 0
            sleep(0.1)
            mouseC.click(mouse.Button.left)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Oh that’s great that you solved your problem, I tried how I suggested but I couldn’t get it to work properly.